# Why encryption key is not working in Postgresql TDE during install? "Unknown data received from encryption_key_command"

Tags: postgresql, security, installation, ubuntu-16.04, tde

I'm trying to install the Postgresql TDE from Cybertech (https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/), specifically version 9.6.12.

I followed the entire guide for default installation:

```
$ wget https://download.cybertec-postgresql.com/postgresql-9.6.12-tde.tar.gz
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev zlibc zlib1g-dev bison flex libssl-dev openssl libperl-dev python-dev
```

I've created a shell /opt/pg_key.sh with this content:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> echo 882fb7c12e80280fd664c69d2d636913

```
$ chmod +x /opt/pg_key.sh
$ tar xvfz postgresql-9.6.12-tde.tar.gz
$ cd postgresql-9.6.12-tde/
$ ./configure --prefix /usr/local/pgsql/ --with-openssl  --with-perl --with-python
$ sudo make install
$ cd contrib/
$ sudo make install
$ sudo chown user:user /usr/local/pgsql/data/
$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data/ -K /opt/pg_key.sh
```

I've got an error in this last command:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user
"user". This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8". The
default text search configuration will be set to "english".
 
Data page checksums are disabled.
Data encryption is enabled. 
fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/pgsql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... FATAL:  Unknown data received from encryption_key_command
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `/opt` on your PATH? Did you set up `encryption_key_command` in `postgresql.conf`?